# HTML Agility pack, can't select a node

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack, nodes

i have the following HTML code

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/products/catalog?hl=de&amp;newwindow=1&amp;q=6411920054105&amp;um=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;cid=12216375657503902223&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=8nWWUOvADonntQbP3IHgDw&amp;ved=0CEgQ8gIwAA" class="psliimg" target="_blank">
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/public/OCXiCAAYqFb859nA0DsbPbBSBR2EYU8IFnl_xtJxG2t1_z_xlLiRjxt5HPa0XFZBT1nch4a1j8PAAr4SVs974R_KnJI83sDB303YlcZQD9L5kmKUdTKXfLfJM_lovWyQcf4UlZkXb8sMarIamxSytCjB-aM=s90-c" alt="iittala Aalto Vase apfelgrün 16cm">
</a>
```

basicly its

```
<a href="" class="" target=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
```

using the html agility pack i cant get the a node with the following `xpath`

```
//a[@class="psliimg]
```

but i was able to get it by selecting its child `<img>` but when i try access any other attribute than href it never works! and if i try to get the count of attributes it gives me one even though there are 3!

here is the original [link](https://www.google.de/search?hl=de&tbm=shop&q=6411920054105&oq=6411920054105&gs_l=products-cc.12...3450.3450.0.4463.1.1.0.0.0.0.334.334.3-1.1.0...0.0...1ac.1.fBfILtFfII0) so you can test , what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you wanting from the htlm code you posted?

I ran it through and tried to test myself and got the same error. So I ran this code below and the text that is written to the console doesn't even contain the attribute `class = psliimg` so I'm not sure what is happening between reading the raw html code from the page and how HAP is handling it.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim web As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load("https://www.google.de/search?hl=de&tbm=shop&q=6411920054105&oq=6411920054105&gs_l=products-cc.12...3450.3450.0.4463.1.1.0.0.0.0.334.334.3-1.1.0...0.0...1ac.1.fBfILtFfII0")

    Dim str = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@href,'12216375657503902223')]").ParentNode.InnerHtml
    'The long munber is contained in the html line and is just used to identify the node I want to select.
    Console.WriteLine(Str)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Here is the output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/products/catalog?hl=de&amp;q=6411920054105&amp;um=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;cid=12216375657503902223">
<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/public/OCXiCAAYqFb859nA0DsbPbBSBR2EYU8IFnl_xtJxG2t1_z_xlLiRjxt5HPa0XFZBT1nch4a1j8PAAr4SVs974R_KnJI83sDB303YlcZQD9L5kmKUdTKXfLfJM_lovWyQcf4UlZkXb8sMarIamxSytCjB-aM=s90-c" alt="iittala Aalto Vase apfelgrün 16cm" height="90" width="90">
</a>
```

So unfortunately you may have to work you `xpath` code to what is above rather than what the web site is saying, please correct me if I'm wrong.

You can also loop through each of the nodes and select what you like.

```
    For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
        'Console.WriteLine(link.ParentNode.InnerHtml)
    Next
```

Sorry not really an answer but didn't know best way to post code snippets.